# Should I install the ubuntu-restricted-extras package?

Tags: 11.10, firefox, flash

I installed Firefox beta 9 and the flash plugin as a .tar.gz file. I unpacked it, installed it and now I can watch YouTube videos smoothly.

But I want to play mp3 codecs and other restricted stuff on my laptop. Should I uninstall the flash plugin for Firefox or just install the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package (which contains everything I need)?

If I install the package without uninstalling the  plugin, will anything bad happen?

Comment: Probably it will get replaced (i'm not sure i use Chromiuim) but anyhow you'll still have flash support and the mp3 codecs if you install the package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it does not matter if you already have flash installed. Personally, I always install the restricted extras and I have never experienced any problems or clashes with flash or any other codecs. I also use Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

This will take care of your audio/video decoding needs, part of what restricted extras or addons installs

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad \
gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
```

Comment: I think you need `gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3` to play mp3s.

Comment: @mikewhatever no you don't.